# An option in SettingsFragment doesn't perform its task

Tags: java, android

I have an option for backup the DB of notes. I added the code of backing up the notes in `onOptionsItemSelected` method in MainActivity and it's works fine. But when I copy the same code to SettingsFragment activity and press that option in my phone, it doesn't work and doesn't show any thing!

Another problem, how I can show a Toast or Snackbar in SettingsFragment activity?!

**Hint:** This is the first time I work with Settings activities. So, I don't know if the `onPreferenceTreeClick` method is the correct method to work with some preferences.

**SettingsFragment activity:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceScreen;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_layout);
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    PreferenceKeys preferenceKeys = new PreferenceKeys(getResources());

    if (key.equals(preferenceKeys.night_mode_pref_key)) {
        SharedPreferences themePrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.THEME_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor themeEditor = themePrefs.edit();
        themeEditor.putBoolean(MainActivity.RECREATE_ACTIVITY, true);

        CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(preferenceKeys.night_mode_pref_key);

        if (checkBoxPreference.isChecked()) {
            themeEditor.putString(MainActivity.SAVED_THEME, MainActivity.DARKTHEME);
        } else {
            themeEditor.putString(MainActivity.SAVED_THEME, MainActivity.LIGHTTHEME);
        }
        themeEditor.apply();

        getActivity().recreate();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {
    PreferenceKeys preferenceKeys = new PreferenceKeys(getResources());

    if(preference.equals(preferenceKeys.backup_db_key))
    {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//com.twitter.i_droidi.mynotesdonation//databases//MyNotes"; // Check...!!!
                String backupDBPath = "MyNotes"; // From SD directory.
                File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Import Successful!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    }

    return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
}
}
```

Comment: "if(preference.equals(preferenceKeys.backup_db_key))" - do you really want to compare the *preference* to ...backup_db_key?

Comment: @0X0nosugar Look at "Hint" in the original post.

Comment: 'preference' is a Preference. I think we'd both expect 'preferenceKeys.backup_db_key' to be a String. If you use equals() on a pair like this, you are invoking Object.equals(), so a) nothing crashes and b) the result is false. I'm not sure about PreferenceTree... either, but please use your IDE to make sure you are comparing the right kind of objects

Comment: if I am correct there and you still have problems just edit your question accordingly